# I am trying to use the MavenToAndroidAnt Python3 to XMPP SMACK 4.1.1, but I am getting some errors

Tags: android, python, xmpp, smack

I am trying to use the MavenToAndroidAnt Python3 to SMACK 4.1.1, but I am getting some errors
I have installed setuptools-15.0b1, python-gnupg-master, httplib2-master

I can't post image yet... i will simulate my cmd prompt

c:\Windows\system32>cd C:\lib

C:\lib>python getMavenArtifactsNg.py -f artifacts.csv -p C:\eclipse\Works\TEsteX
mPP

Downloading smack-android-4.1.1.jar to C:\eclipse\Works\TEsteXmPP/libs/

Downloading smack-android-4.1.1.jar.asc to C:\eclipse\Works\TEsteXmPP/libs/

Downloading smack-android-4.1.1-sources.jar to C:\eclipse\Works\TEsteXmPP/libs-sources/

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "getMavenArtifactsNg.py", line 204, in

```
a.installIn(project)
```

File "getMavenArtifactsNg.py", line 147, in installIn

```
if self.verifySignature(jarSigDest, jarDest):
```

File "getMavenArtifactsNg.py", line 158, in verifySignature

```
gpg = gnupg.GPG()
```

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\gnupg-unknown-py3.4.egg\gnupg\gnupg.py", l
ine 125, in **init**

```
ignore_homedir_permissions=ignore_homedir_permissions,
```

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\gnupg-unknown-py3.4.egg\gnupg_meta.py", l
ine 176, in **init**

```
self.binary  = _util._find_binary(binary)
```

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\gnupg-unknown-py3.4.egg\gnupg_util.py", l
ine 427, in _find_binary

```
raise RuntimeError("GnuPG is not installed!")
```

RuntimeError: GnuPG is not installed!

C:\lib>

____________ artifacts.csv file

org.igniterealtime.smack,smack-android,4.1.1,1357B01865B2503C18453D208CAC2A9678548E35

org.igniterealtime.smack,smack-android-extensions,4.1.1,1357B01865B2503C18453D208CAC2A9678548E35

org.igniterealtime.smack,smack-core,4.1.1,1357B01865B2503C18453D208CAC2A9678548E35

org.igniterealtime.smack,smack-tcp,4.1.1,1357B01865B2503C18453D208CAC2A9678548E35

org.igniterealtime.smack,smack-extensions,4.1.1,1357B01865B2503C18453D208CAC2A9678548E35

org.igniterealtime.smack,smack-experimental,4.1.1,1357B01865B2503C18453D208CAC2A9678548E35

org.igniterealtime.smack,smack-resolver-minidns,4.1.1,1357B01865B2503C18453D208CAC2A9678548E35

org.igniterealtime.smack,smack-sasl-provided,4.1.1,1357B01865B2503C18453D208CAC2A9678548E35

org.jxmpp,jxmpp-core,0.4.2-beta1,1357B01865B2503C18453D208CAC2A9678548E35

org.jxmpp,jxmpp-util-cache,0.4.2-beta1,1357B01865B2503C18453D208CAC2A9678548E35

de.measite.minidns,minidns,0.1.1,4677EF84C286721DA33C09C98D2028BA8AF1E192

EDIT>>>

C:\lib>python getMavenArtifactsNg.py -f artifacts.csv -p C:\eclipse\Works\TEsteX
mPP
Downloading smack-android-4.1.1.jar to C:\eclipse\Works\TEsteXmPP/libs/

Downloading smack-android-4.1.1.jar.asc to C:\eclipse\Works\TEsteXmPP/libs/

Downloading smack-android-4.1.1-sources.jar to C:\eclipse\Works\TEsteXmPP/libs-s
ources/

Exception in thread Thread-8:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "c:\python34\lib\threading.py", line 920, in _bootstrap_inner

```
self.run()
```

File "c:\python34\lib\threading.py", line 868, in run

```
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
```

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\gnupg.py", line 753, in _read_response

```
result.handle_status(keyword, value)
```

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\gnupg.py", line 284, in handle_status

```
raise ValueError("Unknown status message: %r" % key)
```

ValueError: Unknown status message: 'NEWSIG'

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "getMavenArtifactsNg.py", line 204, in

```
a.installIn(project)
```

File "getMavenArtifactsNg.py", line 150, in installIn

```
raise Exception("Could not verify signature for " + jarDest)
```

Exception: Could not verify signature for C:\eclipse\Works\TEsteXmPP/libs/smack-
android-4.1.1.jar

<

I am using Windows 8.1 64X, eclipse SDK 4.2.2 JUNO + ADT

I really want to study the XMPP Smack 4.1.1 documentation, please help me and sorry my english.

Comment: "RuntimeError: GnuPG is not installed!". I'd say this means that you need to install GnuPG.

Comment: thank you very much for answer, I've installed again GnuPG and know i got a new error i searched on google about it, but I dont found nothing